# Proof that the inverse of 3x3 matrix is adjugate matrix divided by it's determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Okay so I need to proof that $$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{det(A)}\begin{bmatrix}(x_2 \times x_3)^T\\(x_3 \times x_1)^T\\(x_1 \times x_2)^T\\\end{bmatrix}$$ Where $x$:s are column vectors. I really don't know where to start, but I know that $det(A)=x_1(x_2 \times x_3)$ if it helps. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Show that this matrix $M$ satisfies $MA=I$. That's enough to conclude that $M=A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{A} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathbf{x}_1 & \mathbf{x}_2 & \mathbf{x}_3  \end{pmatrix} \\[5pt]
  \mathbb{B} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    (\mathbf{x}_2 \times \mathbf{x}_3)^T \\
    (\mathbf{x}_3 \times \mathbf{x}_1)^T \\
    (\mathbf{x}_1 \times \mathbf{x}_2)^T \end{pmatrix} \\[5pt]
  \mathbb{BA} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathbf{x}_{2} \times \mathbf{x}_3 \cdot \mathbf{x}_1 &
    \mathbf{x}_{2} \times \mathbf{x}_3 \cdot \mathbf{x}_2 &
    \mathbf{x}_{2} \times \mathbf{x}_3 \cdot \mathbf{x}_3 \\
    \mathbf{x}_{3} \times \mathbf{x}_1 \cdot \mathbf{x}_1 &
    \mathbf{x}_{3} \times \mathbf{x}_1 \cdot \mathbf{x}_2 &
    \mathbf{x}_{3} \times \mathbf{x}_1 \cdot \mathbf{x}_3 \\
    \mathbf{x}_{1} \times \mathbf{x}_2 \cdot \mathbf{x}_1 &
    \mathbf{x}_{1} \times \mathbf{x}_2 \cdot \mathbf{x}_2 &
    \mathbf{x}_{1} \times \mathbf{x}_2 \cdot \mathbf{x}_3 \\
  \end{pmatrix} \\[5pt]
  &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathbf{x}_{2} \times \mathbf{x}_3 \cdot \mathbf{x}_1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & \mathbf{x}_{3} \times \mathbf{x}_1 \cdot \mathbf{x}_1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \mathbf{x}_{1} \times \mathbf{x}_2 \cdot \mathbf{x}_3 \end{pmatrix} \\[5pt]
  &=
  (\det \mathbb{A})
  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}